# Pysal doesn't recognize some polygon neighbors

Tags: python, polygons, pysal

I'm using the Pysal tool for analyzing several shapefiles (type polygon) that contain the results of segmentations done in QGIS.

I load the shapefile using

`segshp = pysal.weights.Queen.from_shapefile(vect)`

being vect the name of the corresponding shapefile.

The problem is that when I look in the neighbors dictionary, if a polygon shares less than 2 pixels it is not considered a neighbor. Let me show a bit better:

Using ArcGIS, I calculate the polygon neighbors (Analysis tools --> Proximity ---> Polygon neighbors), and for example, polygon 1227 has 4 neighbors as shown in the image.

[Neighbors calculated with ArcGIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAoHp.jpg)

But when loading in Python using Pysal, polygon 1227 has only 3 neighbors and the one missing is 3307, which only shares a 2 pixel border. Same happens with other polygons that share only 1 or 2 pixels. This "threshold" of 2 pixels is just what I have seen analyzing some polygons.

[Neighbors calculated with Pysal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6iEJ.jpg)

Is there anyway of changing that "threshold" in order to consider all neighbors? i've seen in the Pysal documentation and thought maybe it's related to  the command

`pysal.weights.user.min_threshold_dist_from_shapefile`

or something similar, but honestly I got no idea.

I also tried with the pysal.weights.Rook... option, but it recognizes less neighbors and finds more islands.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you verify that your shapefile is valid and that polygon 3307 has 2 vertices in common with polygon 1227?  Try editing the geometry in QGIS is view the vertices of 3307.  Also try repairing the geometry in QGIS or ArcGIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Charles.

Indeed that seems to be the problem. Checking the vertices, although polygon 1227 and 3307 share a common border, they don't share any vertices. Once I edited them manually and corrected a small difference in the coordenates of the new vertices, the Pysal tool recognize them as neighbors. Checking the geometry of the shapefile does not generates any invalid geometries, neither in Arcgis or QGIS.

I'll try to figure a way to create the "missing" vertices in these cases, so I can "fix" the geometry before the Pysal line (any ideas for this matter are welcome).

Anyway, for now and respecting the original question the issue has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Even in the current latest version, Pysal is not able to handle certain cases, such as the case of common MultiPoints like this one:

[image]

Using convex_hull is probably not the best for efficiency, but I needed correctness more...